# Dns.Resolve() vs Dns.GetHostEntry()

Tags: c#, socket, tcpclient

O método `Resolve` está como obsoleto e a Microsoft orienta a usar o `GetHostEntry`. No entanto ao usar `GetHostEntry` ocorre a exceção:

> Este host não é conhecido

Quando uso `Resolve` não há exceção e o programa funciona corretamente.

Os Ip's usados são da LAN a qual meu pc está conectado. Fiz um teste colocando um Ip remoto, da Google, e então o `GetHostEntry` não gerou exceção, ou seja, ele não funciona com os Ip's da minha lan.

Como posso resolver esse problema usando `GetHostEntry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o método [`GetHostEntry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry.aspx) tenta fazer uma [pesquisa inversa](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730980(v=ws.11).aspx) antes de retornar o IP, se esse procedimento falhar, é retornado o erro [`WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) -  *Host not found*.

Como alternativa, você pode usar o método [`GetHostAddresses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx), que diferente do método `GetHostEntry`, não é feita nenhuma pesquisa inversa, o IP é imediatamente devolvido como resultado.

Exemplo:

```
public static void DoGetHostAddresses(string hostname)
{
    IPAddress[] ips;    
    ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);

    Console.WriteLine("GetHostAddresses({0}) returns:", hostname);

    foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)</kbd>